# PuTTy error : Unable to open connection, Network error Invalid arguments

Tags: connection, putty

Problem:

- Starting `Putty.exe` from downloaded folder works well.
- Connection Error when I run it from a different folder after copying `putty.exe`.

[image: Added Black path where ip address of server is shown in error]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the issue, I was working on virtual machine where most of directories including desktop is stored in external disk that was `H:/`

So i copied `putty.exe` in systems c-drive/random folder, and was able to connect successfully.

Comment: This error started happening to me as well, and I can workaround it by running it off my C: drive...but that doesn't answer the question of why it happens. I should be able to run the executable off a mapped drive (I was able to previously).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you did not copy the supported files I believe - You only copied the `putty.exe` which is not alone enough.

Comment: But i downloaded only putty.exe file, so there was no supporting files. And it's working fine from downloaded folder